# "Script" command in Bash on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell, script

quick question regarding the "script" command in Bash on a Mac OSX 10.8.4 system.

In any other bash environment on Fedora, CentOS, etc; when I use the script command it just begins recording with no issue.

However, on the Mac OS as soon as I type script it goes and starts displaying my entire file system as if I used the "tree /" command. Identical to it, actually. Once it finally stops it beings recording like usual.

It there a reason for this strange behavior? I do have a tree command installed for this OS (as it didn't come pre-installed) perhaps this is causing some issues?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Run `type script` and see what you get?

Comment: @anubhava
I get the output `script is /usr/bin/script`

Comment: By any chance the tree command is running from your bashrc or other scripts started from bashrc? script starts a subshell.

Comment: Does it do this if you run it as a different user? I'm thinking you may have something strange in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` or something.

Comment: You guys were right! I had a strange command entered into my .bashrc that, when run; does the aforementioned issue. I can't remember why I had it in there or for what purpose. Removing it fixed the problem!
Oh; the entry was `find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'`